# Need to replace empty cells with "Blank" upon query in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, coalesce

I am trying to deal with empty cells and get the data with empty cells filled with something like "Blank" string upon querying in PostgreSQL. My query looks like this :

```
SELECT t_id, a_date, c_date, o_s_date, o_e_date, 
   ttr_hr, ttn_min, d_sub_outage_impact,  
   tkt_source, d_vertical, d_grp, city, state
FROM r.all_t_event b

   Left Outer Join(
   select i_number,status,o_group
   From r.hpd_help_desk
   Group by i_number,status,o_group) a on a.i_number =b.t_id
Where close_date >= to_timestamp('10/05/2017','mm/dd/yyyy')
and t_condition = 'Outage'
and (a_grp like '%NOC%' or a.o_group like '%NOC%')
and t_id not in ('INC8788','INC26116')
and a.status = '5'
```

Tried a lot with the CASE statement in the SELECT statement, but I always get an error something like "ERROR: syntax error at or near "WHEN" when I tried with something like:

```
CASE 
WHEN d_outage_min = " " then "blank" else d_outage_min
WHEN v_outage_min = " " then "blank" else v_outage_min //Error occurred here
.....END
```

And got an error something like "ERROR: syntax error at or near "CASE" when I tried:

```
CASE 
WHEN d_outage_min = " " then "blank" else d_outage_min
END

CASE //Error occurred here

WHEN v_outage_min = " " then "blank" else v_outage_min
END
CASE...END
```

Will be glad to have a way out/Coalesce statement syntax/anything that could help.
Thanks again!

Comment: `"blank"` is an identifier, not a string: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: [So do you have your answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: I did get my answer with COALESCE.  I had to work on the Time stamp and the numeric type field a lil more to get the entire query fixed. Thank you so much for all your inputs, had been extremely helpful! Apologies for the delayed response.

Answer (score 1):

It's a plain syntax error. ***Values*** require single quotes (`''`), not double quotes (`""`), which denote ***identifiers***. This works:

```
CASE WHEN d_outage_min = ' ' THEN '"blank"' ELSE d_outage_min END
```

Assuming "empty" means a single blank. For the empty string use `''`, for `NULL` use [`COALESCE()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL).

[Read the manual here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than introducing the CASE statement, just surround your column (ie: col below) with the following.  NULLIF will replace col with NULL if it finds an empty string.  And COALESCE will replace the NULL with 'blank'.  REPLACE function will not find an empty string, so this is the only way.

This will handle an empty string.

COALESCE(NULLIF(col,''), 'blank')

This will handle an empty string and a string with spaces.

COALESCE(NULLIF(TRIM(col),''), 'blank')

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for. Concise and appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

CASE works in these two ways. First way, when the test is repeated each line:

```
CASE 
  WHEN name = 'john' then 1
  WHEN address LIKE '% road' then 2
  WHEN somecolumn > somevalue THEN 3
  ELSE 4
END
```

Think of CASE and END as the start and end markers. Each line between the markers must be of the form `WHEN {logical test that is true or false} THEN {value to return if true}`

You cannot have an ELSE on each line; if the test is false, the next test is run. **This is why you got the first "error near WHEN"** - by putting an else on the first line, Postgres was expecting you to END the case block, not issue another WHEN test

You can only have one else, as the last thing. If nothing has resulted in true, the value returned by ELSE is given. If there is no ELSE, null is given

All the values/columns you specify after THEN have to be type compatible

---

Second way is a short form where one variable is tested for a number of different values:

```
CASE gender
  WHEN 'male' THEN 1
  WHEN 'female' THEN 2
  ELSE 'not specified'
END
```

This is equivalent to

```
CASE 
  WHEN gender = 'male' THEN 1
  WHEN gender = 'female' THEN 2
  ELSE 'not specified'
END
```

And all the same rules apply. If using the short form you cannot switch form half way through. All your WHEN statements only contain a value and it will be compared against the value declared after the CASE with an "equals" test. This form is less often used, and not implemented in some DB

The second error you got ("error near CASE") was because you tried to use two case statements next to each other without anything to separate them, like a string concatenation, or a comma

---

COALESCE is a function that takes many arguments, it scans the arguments provided for the first one that isn't null, and returns it

```
COALESCE(anullcolumn, anothernull, athirdnull, anonnull) -- the value of anonnull will be returned
```

This is conceptually equivalent to

```
CASE
  WHEN anullcolumn IS NOT NULL THEN anullcolumn
  WHEN anothernull IS NOT NULL THEN anothernull
  WHEN athirdnull IS NOT NULL THEN athirdnull
  WHEN anonnull IS NOT NULL THEN anonnull
END
```

Just a lot nicer to read and write

As Erwin has pointed out, once you fix these syntax errors caused by your case statements being all mangled, the compiler will move on to examining your strings and start complaining about those. Use an apostrophe to denote string in sql, not a speech mark

```
'This is a string in sql'
"Not a string"
```

Postgres uses speech marks to to denote table and column names that are case sensitive. Don't use them if you can help it

---

Your attempts should look like:

```
CASE 
WHEN d_outage_min = ' ' then 'blank' else d_outage_min
END as d_outage_min,
CASE
WHEN v_outage_min = ' ' then 'blank' else v_outage_min
END as v_outage_min
```

Two case statements, one per column that might be blank (a single space character), separated by comma

Note that null and space are different things! If your columns are NULL then testing them against a single space character will not work! This is how you test them, if they're null:

```
CASE 
WHEN d_outage_min IS NULL then 'blank' else d_outage_min
END as d_outage_min,
CASE
WHEN v_outage_min IS NULL then 'blank' else v_outage_min
END as v_outage_min
```

Or

```
COALESCE(d_outage_min, 'blank') as d_outage_min,
COALESCE(v_outage_min, 'blank') as v_outage_min
```

Coalesce is more compact. It will only work if the columns are null. If they're a single space character, you must case when